# Is there a faster way to generate random string in ruby?

Tags: ruby

```
  start_time = Time.now
  1000000.times do
        rand(36**1024).to_s(36)
  end
  end_time = Time.now
  puts end_time - start_time
```

235 seconds.

Is there a faster way to generate random string in ruby?

Comment: A side note: use [Benchmark](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/Benchmark.html). `require 'benchmark'; Benchmark.measure { 1000000.times {rand(36**1024).to_s(36) } }`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your target system has **/dev/urandom** you can read random bytes from it. It should be faster. Here is code with benchmark. Some Ruby libs use this approach to generate random things.

```
Benchmark.bm do|b|

    b.report("Ruby #rand  ") do
      100000.times do
        big_key = rand(36**1024).to_s(36)
      end
    end

    b.report("/dev/urandom") do
      File.open("/dev/urandom",File::RDONLY || File::NONBLOCK || File::NOCTTY) do |f|
        100000.times do
          big_key = f.readpartial(512).unpack("H*")[0]
        end
      end
    end
end
```

Here you can see benchmark results on 100000, 1024 char long random strings...

```
       user     system      total        real
Ruby #rand   31.750000   0.080000  31.830000 ( 32.909136)
/dev/urandom  0.810000   5.870000   6.680000 (  6.974276)
```

Comment: I like your idea, but the `big_key = f.readpartial(512).unpack("H*")[0]` line in your second benchmark is executed once only. You should use the same measurement method as in the first case, i.e. `100000.times`, and rerun the benchmark.

Comment: Idea is to read from /dev/urandom until you get enough random bytes.

Comment: I see, but in total your code reads exactly 512 bytes instead of 10000*512 bytes. You're benchmarking a *single* execution instead of 10k executions.

Answer (score 2):

Don't need to do `36**1024` `1000000 times`

```
val=36**1024
1000000.times do
  rand(val).to_s(36)
end
```

This will definitely save some time

Answer (score 1):

You can shuffle the string to get random strings

```
array = rand(36**1024).to_s(36).split(//)

start_time = Time.now
1000000.times do
  array.shuffle.join
end
end_time = Time.now
puts end_time - start_time
```

#=> 126 seconds

Comment: You're kind of cheating here, since you do most of the actual randomization out of the timed loop.

Answer (score 1):

What about using securerandom?

```
require 'securerandom'

start_time = Time.now
1000000 .times do
  SecureRandom.base64(1024)
end
end_time = Time.now
puts end_time - start_time
```

Answer (score 0):

```
1.9.3p194 :113 >   
1.9.3p194 :114 >     start_time = Time.now
 => 2012-10-16 19:51:45 +0530 
1.9.3p194 :115 >   1000000.times do
1.9.3p194 :116 >            (Object.new.hash.to_s << Object.new.hash.to_s)[0..35]
1.9.3p194 :117?>     end
 => 1000000 
1.9.3p194 :118 >   end_time = Time.now
 => 2012-10-16 19:51:46 +0530 
1.9.3p194 :119 >   puts end_time - start_time
1.8252512
 => nil 
1.9.3p194 :120 >
```

=> 1.8 sec

So in short `Object.new.hash.to_s`

Comment: comments. XD  cant... under... standddd

Comment: (Object.new.hash.to_s << Object.new.hash.to_s)[0..35]